# Checkbox In Oracle ADF Table: Not getting or setting data

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have an application written in Oracle ADF.

In it, I have a table by which I need to add a checkbox column which maps back to a VARCHAR column.

I created a transient boolean attribute in my View Object which properly sets the real attribute. This setup works perfectly in my Business Component Tester/Browser. However, in my JSPX, the table column which gets the checkbox based on the transient attribute, does not get or set data.

This setup is done exactly as shown in this blog: [Adding Boolean Checkbox to Table Component in Oracle ADF](http://www.baigzeeshan.com/2010/05/adding-boolean-checkbox-to-table.html)  . For instance, my real attribute (which is the varchar/string), called isCurrent. I created my transient column called isCurrentBoolean (Boolean data type), which respectively has the checkbox property set. I used the Row Implementation class to properly set both attributes - which works perfectly in the ADF Business Component Tester/Browser.

However, in my table on the JSPX page, the records whom have the checkbox enabled, don't show as checked. And when i try to set data, my commit process does not run period (no errors, it literally doesnt run).

Any ideas?

Thank you!

**Update 01:**

I have my transient boolean attribute properly getting data based on the string/varchar attribute, now its just the setting data part thats not working.

In the Row Implementation Class, I added a message to fire every time the setter runs for IsCurrentBoolean. It does not fire when the checkbox is checked. I have autosubmit set to true. I will see if there is anything else i can do, but i may just add a method in my appliction module and have it fired in the value change listener of the checkbox - as a workaround.

JSPX Code:

```
<af:column sortProperty="IsCurrentBoolean" sortable="false" 
    headerText="Current?" id="c2" width="50">
<af:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{row.IsCurrentBoolean}" id="sbc1" 
    autoSubmit="true" />
```

Row Impl Code: This is my setter for the transient attribute (Which sets the real attribute):

```
    if (value) {
        this.setProvPracIsCurrent("Y");
        setAttributeInternal(ISCURRENTBOOLEAN, value);
    } else {
        this.setProvPracIsCurrent("N");
        setAttributeInternal(ISCURRENTBOOLEAN, value);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This guy is a savior: http://adfreusablecode.blogspot.com/2012/09/afselectbooleancheckbox-with-y-n-values.html

Basically, i got rid of the transient attribute and ADF Table column using the transient attribute.

Instead, I used the attribute which maps back to the database (String/VarChar).

Added the attribute onto my table, this created an input text box. Converted the input text to a checkbox. Deleted the validator tag nested in the converted checkbox.

Created a converted a converter to translate between Boolean and String. Create a class with the following code:

```
  import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;

import org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.ClientConverter;


public class YNConverter implements Converter, ClientConverter {
    public YNConverter() {
        super();
    }
  public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, String value)
   {
     return "true".equals(value) ? "Y" : "N";
   }

   public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, Object value)
   {
     return "Y".equals(value) ? "true" : "false";
   }

   public String getClientLibrarySource(FacesContext facesContext)
   {
     return null;
   }

   public Collection<String> getClientImportNames()
   {
     return Collections.emptySet();
   }

   public String getClientScript(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent)
   {
     return null;
   }

   public String getClientConversion(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent)
   {
     return null;
   }
}
```

In faces-config.xml, add the class and define it as a Converter. Named it YNConverter.

In the JSP page, my checkbox looks like the following:

```
   <af:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{row.bindings.ProvPracIsCurrent.inputValue}"
                                                      label="#{bindings.Ppsqnd4UppUpViewView.hints.ProvPracIsCurrent.label}"
                                                      required="#{bindings.Ppsqnd4UppUpViewView.hints.ProvPracIsCurrent.mandatory}"
                                                      shortDesc="#{bindings.Ppsqnd4UppUpViewView.hints.ProvPracIsCurrent.tooltip}"
                                                      id="it12"
                                                      converter="YNConverter"/>
```

Boom. Done.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you made it exactly like the post, did you also made the attribute to be "ALWAYS"  in the updateable section!

Also I'd like you to include the page snippet that have the checkbox

Comment: Yes Updatable is set to Always. I'll include some snippets of code shortly

Comment: I added a code snippet. If you notice, i have the value property set to #{row.IsCurrentBoolean}. It was originally #{row.bindings.IsCurrentBoolean}. Unfortunately, the row.bindings.IsCurrentBoolean didnt return any data or positive results. When i changed it to #{row.IsCurrentBoolean}, it atleast was getting data properly.